# Key present in bucket but the api is returning "Key cannot be null or empty" for few key

Tags: .net, couchbase

I am using Couchbase.NET client 2.4.8.1 to retrieve the document from a bucket.
We have 4 data and query nodes and 2 index nodes.

```
IDocumentResult<T> document = _bucket.GetDocument<T>(key);
```

FOr some of the key we are able to fetch the data but for few keys even it is there in the bucket and we are able to fetch it from workbench the api is returning "Key cannot be null or empty." with the response status as "ClientFailure". Please help

The code snippet -

```
            var config = new ClientConfiguration
            {
                Servers = new List<Uri> {
                   new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8091")

               }
            };

            //create the cluster and pass in the RBAC user
            var cluster = new Cluster(config);
            var credentials = new PasswordAuthenticator("xxx_yyy", "*****");
            cluster.Authenticate(credentials);

            //open the new bucket
            var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("xxx_yyy", "*****");

            var airportPOI = bucket.GetDocument<dynamic>("Travel::A23::A24");
            Console.Write(airportPOI);


            var queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
                            .Statement("select * from xxx_yyy use keys 'Travel::A23::A24'");

            var result = bucket.Query<dynamic>(queryRequest);
            Console.Write(result);
```

GetDocument returns client failure with the message "Key cannot be null or 
empty".
But same N1QL query returns result. Please help

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, my only guess is that the `key` you're sending might be null or empty.

Comment: Hi Matthew - Thanks for replying. This is happening for few of the keys not for all the use cases.

Comment: Could you please post the minimum code to reproduce? Are any of the nodes in your cluster behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi - I have added the code snippet, please look into it

Comment: It looks like this was posted in the Couchbase forums too: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/key-present-in-bucket-but-the-api-is-returning-key-cannot-be-null-or-empty-for-few-key/19915, which currently has a response.